# How do i make discount percentage of products in Laravel?

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, discount

```js
product_discount[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_discount"]').val();

if (product_type[pos] == 'standard') {
    var row_unit_operator = unit_operator[rowindex].slice(0, unit_operator[rowindex].indexOf(","));
    var row_unit_operation_value = unit_operation_value[rowindex].slice(0, unit_operation_value[rowindex].indexOf(","));
    if (row_unit_operator == '*') {
        product_price[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val() / row_unit_operation_value;
    } else {
        product_price[rowindex] = $('input[name="edit_unit_price"]').val() * row_unit_operation_value;
    }
```

Comment: Hi  Would you care to add a description of what is going wrong? Error messages? Miscalculation? Describe what you are trying to do and what doesn't work.

Comment: I want to come up with a product discount  in percentage

Comment: Please put the description in the question. People will not read all the comments. Also describe what doesn't work. See the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.